# Make urls absolute by inserting base tag in html string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have a html string that can contain any variation of elements, including anchors with relative and non-relative URL's:

```
var html = '<div><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Link</a><a href="/questions">Link</a><a href="">Link</a></div>';
```

Now I want to get a list of all the URLs:

```
var list = [];
$(html).find('a').each(function(){
    list.push(this.href);
});
```

However this will result in a list with relative URLs based on the page that's executing the code.

Is it possible to make the relative URLs absolute by maybe inserting a base tag somehow? Or is there any better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the result of that code and the desired (expected) output?

Comment: Well for example the string could be the source of stackoverflow.com,  so the result should be `['https://stackoverflow.com', https://stackoverflow.com/questions', 'https://stackoverflow.com']`.

Comment: `this.href` should get you the absolute URL. Granter, it will get you the absolute URL which includes the domain this code is executed on instead of the domain the HTML extract is from but that can easily be fixed by replacing one with the other.

Comment: Yeah that's right. So you could set the base tag of the page that's executing the code. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the original `href` value then use `.getAttribute('href')` to get it instead of `.href`:

```js
var html = '<div><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Link</a><a href="/questions">Link</a><a href="">Link</a></div>';

// this function takes an url and deremines wether it is an absolute path or not
function isAbsolute(url) {
    return url.indexOf("//") === 0 || /^[a-z]+:\/\//i.test(url);
}

var list = [],
    baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";       // the base url
$(html).find('a').each(function() {
    var href = this.getAttribute('href');    // get the raw href attribute value
    if(isAbsolute(href)) {                   // if the href is of an absolute path
        list.push(href);                     // then push it as it is
    } else {                                 // otherwise
        list.push(baseUrl + href);           // append it to the base url and then push it
    }
});

console.log(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah that works. But I wanted to use the browser's native ability to detect relative urls by using the base tag somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the URL

1st case: The URL starts with protocol, like https://

Here you can leave the URL unchanged, it will work from anywhere.

2nd case: The URL starts with /

In this case, you need to prepend `window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host` to your URL

3rd case: Anything else, except those which start with ../

In this case, you will need to add the URL to `window.location.href + "/"`, but without the hash part and without the /yourpagename.

4th case: The URL starts with ../

In this case you will need to remove as many parts in the URL as many ../ is your href is starting with + 1. for instance:

Loaded URL is: http://foo.bar/a/b/c/d

href is ../../e/f

You will need to prepend http://foo.bar/a/ to e/f

Comment: Yeah that's why I thought it would be more convenient to use the base tag somehow.

Comment: @J.Doe you can get the baseURL like this var baseUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]; but you will need to make sure you do not prepend it to URLs starting with ../ or https://, so you will end up writing a function for this and handling separate cases anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var html = '<div><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Link</a><a href="/questions">Link</a><a href="">Link</a></div>';

var list = [];
var list2 = [];
$(html).find('a').each(function(){
    list.push($(this).attr('href'));
    list2.push(this.href);
});
console.log(list);
console.log(list2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure javaScript,

```js
const html = '<div><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Link</a><a href="/questions">Link</a><a href="">Link</a></div>';

// Create a dummy DOM element and add the string to it. Then, you can manipulate it like any DOM element.
const node = document.createElement('div');
node.innerHTML = html;

// Select all tags with the attribute `href`
const tags = node.querySelectorAll('[href]');

var urls = [];

// Loop through tags
for(var i = 0, length = tags.length; i < length; i++) {
  var link = tags[i].href;
  urls.push(link);
}

console.log(urls);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for reference.
If you want to convert a relative url (of any kind) to an absolute one, and you know the base (you always know the base), just need to do:

```
const makeAbsoluteHref = (url, base) => new URL(url, base).href;
```